# Python code for string modification doesn't work properly

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

This piece of code's supposed to take in a string input and output another string which is just the modified version of the input string. I can't get it to work though.

It is supposed to output a string in which each letter is the next alphabetic letter of the input string.But upon running the code, its simply outputs the same input string instead of the modified string.

```
def str_changer(string):

       string_list = list(string)
       alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
       positions = []
       for letter in string_list:
         positions.append(alphabets.index(letter))
       for each in positions:
         each = each + 1
       for each in string_list:
         string_list[string_list.index(each)] = 
       alphabets[positions[string_list.index(each)]]

       another = ''.join(string_list)



       return another



    lmao = raw_input('Enter somin\'')
    print str_changer(lmao)
```

Comment: `string_list[string_list.index(each)] = ` are you missing the end of this line?

Comment: @DavyM I think they've wrapped it with the next line so `string_list[string_list.index(each)] = 
       alphabets[positions[string_list.index(each)]]`

Comment: Instead of writing out the alphabet you can just use `from string import ascii_lowercase` which gives you `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: That `each = each +1` seems iffy and unlikely to result in much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you. You should use `%` to account for `z`.

The main point is you don't need to explicitly build a list of positions.

```
def str_changer(string):

    string_list = list(string)
    alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    new_string_list = []

    for letter in string_list:
        new_string_list.append(alphabets[(alphabets.index(letter)+1) % len(alphabets)])

    return ''.join(new_string_list)

lmao = raw_input('Enter somin\'')
print str_changer(lmao)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do it in just **1-line**:

```
s = 'abcdz'
print(''.join(chr(ord(letter) + 1) if letter != 'z' else 'a' for letter in s))
# bcdea
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('b')
98
>>> chr(ord('a') + 1)
'b'
```